# Why vector push_back call twice in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

In the following program, I have created 3 object of class Person and pushed that object into vector container. After that, the display function is called using a range based for loop and printing the name and age.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
 
using namespace std; 

class Person
{
    private:
        string _name;
        int _age;
        
    public:
    
    Person()
    {
    
    }

    Person(string name, int age) : _name(name), _age(age)
    {
        
    }

    void Display()
    {
        cout<<"_name : "<<_name<<" => "<<"_age : "<<_age<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person p1("User1", 20);
    Person p2("User2", 30);
    Person p3("User3", 25);
    
    vector<Person> per(3);
    
    per.push_back(p1);
    per.push_back(p2);
    per.push_back(p3);
    
    for(auto obj : per)
    {
        obj.Display();
    }
}
```

But I don't understad what am I missing here to get output

```
_name :  => _age : -1
_name :  => _age : -1
_name :  => _age : -1
_name : User1 => _age : 20
_name : User2 => _age : 30
_name : User3 => _age : 25
```

instead of

```
_name : User1 => _age : 20
_name : User2 => _age : 30
_name : User3 => _age : 25
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `vector<Person> per(3);` creates a `vector` containing 3 default-initialized `Person`.

Comment: `vector<Person> per(3);` The 3 here initializes the vector to the size 3 and populates it with 3 objects. That's not necessary, the vector will grow with every `push_back`.

Comment: Replace `vector<Person> per(3);` with `vector<Person> per;` will fix your issue

Comment: You want `/*const*/ std::vector<Person> per{p1, p2, p3};`

Comment: Removing default constructor of `Person` would might help to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define the vector:

```
vector<Person> per(3);
```

you set the size to `3`, which means three default-constructed elements will be created and added to the vector.

You then add three more, so you have a total of six elements in the vector.

If you only want your three elements there are a few alternatives:

1. Reserve the memory only, do not set the size:

   ```
   vector<Person> per;
   per.reserve(3);  // Allocates memory for 3 elements, doesn't set the size
   per.push_back(p1);
   per.push_back(p2);
   per.push_back(p3);
   ```
2. Don't push back, use indexing to set the elements:

   ```
   vector<Person> per(3);
   per[0] = p1;
   per[1] = p2;
   per[2] = p3;
   ```
3. Initialize the vector with the elements you want:

   ```
   vector<Person> per = {
       { "User1", 20 },
       { "User2", 30 },
       { "User3", 25 }
   };
   ```

Comment: Last one (the initialization) even allows `const` vector :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining more about vector.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a vector of size 3, and after that, you are adding 3 more elements to that vector. Try printing out the number of elements stored in your vector (`per.size()`) after inserting your 3 persons.